# Magento 2 invoice pdf for COD orders before payment

Tags: magento-2.1, orders, order-status, cash-on-delivery, order-state

Is there's any way to get invoice print in magento 2 before actually invoicing the order. 
This is needed for cash on delivery order as invoice copy need to sent to customer with order to customer in cod.
If the shipping is successful and payment is received, then admin would mark the order as complete.

Ps: I am still confused with COD payment order flow in magento 2. I need help to accomplish the proper order flow for COD orders processing. The above might be solved with custom order status. Need guidance regarding order processing flow for COD orders in magento 2.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Gaurav you will have to add `protected $_canCapture = true;` on vendor\magento\module-offline-payments\Model\Cashondelivery.php after adding above line you will get three options during submitting invoice online capture, offline capture, not capture. in case of COD choose not capture and set order status as per your conditions.